# Samsung/Android dev, how to add Floating mode

Tags: android, popupwindow

I've already added Android/Samsung MultiWindow mode, by adding some line inside the Manifest file. Unfortunately I can't find out how to add Floating/Popup mode to get something like this picture (note that the apps are floating).
[image: floating apps]
<sub>(source: [isource.com](http://isource.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Screenshot_2013-02-02-21-29-34-600x375.png))</sub>

Somebody knows how to add the support for this view mode?

Comment: Try here:https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

Comment: I think that this floating feature is inside Android's SDK like the Multiwindow one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your manifest contains the following somewhere inside the application tag:

```
<meta-data  
 android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.penwindow.enable"    
 android:value="true"/>
```

More info [here](http://developer.samsung.com/board/download.do?bdId=T000000144&attachId=0000000001)